# Connecting Excel 2016 to Postgres

Tags: excel, postgresql

I am trying to have Postgres show as one of the data connection in Excel 2016. Following [MS Office instructions](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Connect-to-a-PostgreSQL-database-Power-Query-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4) I installed Ngpsql data provider. I used msi for installation so according to the instructions provided in the wizard the dlls were registered in GAC and the provider was registered in machine.config (I checked - the entry is there).
Yet Postgres is still not showing as an option in Excel > Data > New Query > From Database list.
Searching the web shows old out of date discussions. Developers of of Ngpsql direct questions to Stack Overflow. So please help.

Answer (score 4):

Postgres data can be used in Excel 2016 but it requires the ODBC driver and an external setup of the database server. As far as I can tell the Npgsql drivers do not work with my version of Excel which is 2016 MSO 32-bit a.k.a "Home Premium".

The Postgres ODBC driver is available here: https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/ Download and install the latest version. It should install without needing a system reboot.

Setup a DSN (I used machine) using the ODBC Data Sources (XX-bit) setup application. The driver version needs to match your Excel version.

After testing the connection in the setup screen, open Excel 2016 and use the Data -> New Query -> From Other Sources -> From ODBC menu to open the query screens. This seems to be the most modern interface available in Excel.

Comment: Why Text utf8 can't display ok? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228209/how-can-get-string-utf8-when-connect-from-excel-to-postgresql